# Включенный checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня есть код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.39460.js"></script> 
    <body>
    <br><br>
        <div class="container"> 
                    <input type="checkbox" class="fire-check" />
            <br><br><br>
            <section>   
                <div class="tn-box tn-box-color-1">
                    <p>Подождите, оно исчезает позже</p>
                    <div class="tn-progress"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tn-box tn-box-color-2">
                    <p>Оно исчезнет позже позднего</p>
                    <div class="tn-progress"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tn-box tn-box-color-3">
                    <p>Исчезает последним!<p>
                    <div class="tn-progress"></div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Но что бы открывались модальные окна, нужно активировать checkbox, как сделать что бы при открытии страницы, эти модальные окна автоматически открывались. Без checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var modals = $('.container').find('.tn-box');
    modals.hide(); // если через css не спрятаны
    modals.each(function(idx, modal){
        $(modal).delay(1000*idx).fadeIn();
    })
});
```

- [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)
- [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)